# We have more than 12,000 anonymous feedback votes

Tags: discussion, site-statistics

Just a heads up for those of you who have access to the so-called moderator tools (10k+), you can see [various statistics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/summary?filter=all) related to the [anonymous feedback mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130095/anonymous-user-feedback-about-my-posts) (i.e. that from persons of no account), and also see list of those post which recive better or worse anonymous feedback then votes and those that simple recieve very positive or negative anonymous feedback.

I was a bit surprised today when I noticed that we have recieved more than 12k such votes which averages more than one per question and is almost 10% of the more usual sort of votes.

For those that can't see it right now, it is running about 2:1 positive.

---

In addition [sam.saffron](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/1) has provided a [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) [query that can extract this data on a per user basis](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts) (which I believe gets around the 10k limit for the on-site pages).

Comment: Didn't know this existed. TIL. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Manishearth I think you get the "Was this post useful to you?" question if you're not logged in.

Comment: @Bernhard: Oh, I know about that. I also know of the mod-only stats that are there about this. I didn't know about the 10k anonymous feedback stats page, the link is sorta buried under the rest of the `stats` tab of `/tools`. This one is way more robust and useful than the mod-only tool (which gives us an overall idea of the situation only) :D

Comment: I think you mean persons **with** no account: i.e. unregistered visitors, visitors who are not logged in. "Persons **of** no account" means insignificant / worthless people.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers It's an old joke from the [jargon file](http://catb.org/jargon/oldversions/jarg440.txt) playing on exactly that implication. If you still find it objectionable I'll change it. Or you can.